# What does "local to a blueprint" mean?

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, decorator

I'm having some trouble understanding the difference between [Blueprint.errorhandler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) and [Blueprint.app_errorhandler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Blueprint.app_errorhandler). According the API document(emphasis mine):

> `errorhandler(code_or_exception)`
>
> Registers an error handler that becomes active for this blueprint
>   only. Please be aware that routing does not happen **local to a
>   blueprint** so an error handler for 404 usually is not handled by a
>   blueprint unless it is caused inside a view function. Another special
>   case is the 500 internal server error which is always looked up from
>   the application.

AFAIK, a blueprint object in Flask is "a set of operations which can be registered on an application, even multiple times".

My questions are:

1. How can an error be local to a set of operations?
2. How can a view function cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'local' means that in relation to the routes a blueprint registers. Blueprint routes are always prefixed by the name you registered your blueprint with, so they are naturally grouped and in a URL path topology sense they have locality. 'nonlocal' then is any view not associated with the blueprint; they'll have a different prefix or no prefix at all.

View functions can raise [*exceptions*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), and specific exceptions (anything derived from [`HTTPException`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException)) have a HTTP error code associated with them. `@blueprint.errorhandler()` registers a handler for such exceptions or associated HTTP error codes.

What the documentation is stating is that errors raised *during routing* (such as the 404 `NotFound` error) do not have a view yet and therefor you can't route that error to a specific blueprint either.

Under the hood, when routing succeeds to find a view to handle the request, `request.blueprint` is set to the associated registered blueprint that corresponds to that view. If then an error occurs and an error handler needs to be found, the `request.blueprint` value lets Flask find 'local' error handlers.

Comment: So `@blueprint.errorhandler()` checks for where the exception occurred(and it does nothing if the exception turns out to be "nonlocal", i.e. not defined inside this specific blueprint), while `@blueprint.app_errorhandler()` does, right?

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't precise enough; I've updated it. So *once a view is found*, Flask can route errors to right blueprint-specific error handler. `app_errorhandler()` basically calls `Flask.errorhandler` and thus will be used for all (matching) errors that can't be routed to a specific blueprint instead.